# Facing error of Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, firebase, nullpointerexception

[image: null object reference]

I'm unable to fix this bug. This bug is showing when I want to remove an entry from firebase.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double com.educationalappspk.financemgt4ortho.ExpenseInfo.getTuition()' on a null object reference
at com.educationalappspk.financemgt4ortho.TransactionActivityAdapter$2.onDataChange(TransactionActivityAdapter.java:157)
at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:191)

```
public class TransactionActivityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TransactionData> {

    private Activity context;
    private List<TransactionData> transactionDataList;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private String uid;

    public TransactionActivityAdapter(Activity context, List<TransactionData> transactionDataList) {
        super(context, R.layout.recent_transaction, transactionDataList);
        this.context =  context;
        this.transactionDataList = transactionDataList;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return transactionDataList.size();
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public TransactionData getItem(int position) {
        return transactionDataList.get(position);
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.expenselist_child,null,false);
        TransactionData transactionData = transactionDataList.get(position);
        ImageButton imageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.expenseListDeleteButton);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Item selected " + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder1.setMessage("Delete this transactions?");
                builder1.setCancelable(true);
                builder1.setPositiveButton(
                        "Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                onDeleteItem(position);
                            }
                        });

                builder1.setNegativeButton(
                        "No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                alert11.show();
            }
        });

        TextView date,category,amount,type;
        date = view.findViewById(R.id.expense_list_child_date);
        category = view.findViewById(R.id.expense_list_child_category);
        amount = view.findViewById(R.id.expense_list_child_amount);
        type = view.findViewById(R.id.expense_list_child_type);
        date.setText(transactionData.getDate());
        category.setText(transactionData.getCategory());
        amount.setText(String.valueOf(transactionData.getAmount()) );
        type.setText(transactionData.getType());
        return view;
    }

    public void onDeleteItem(final int position){
        final TransactionData transactionData = transactionDataList.get(position);
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        uid = user.getUid();
        final DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(uid).child("transactions");
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(transactionData.getDate());
            DailyData dailyData = new DailyData(date);
            if(Integer.parseInt(dailyData.getDay())/10==0){
                String d = "0" + dailyData.getDay();
                dailyData.setDay(d);
            }
            if(Integer.parseInt(dailyData.getMonth())/10==0){
                String m = "0" + dailyData.getMonth();
                dailyData.setMonth(m);
            }
            final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(uid).child("expenseInfo").child(dailyData.getYear()).child(dailyData.getMonth());
            databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    ExpenseInfo expenseInfo = dataSnapshot.getValue(ExpenseInfo.class);
                    Log.d("hi", "onDataChange: " +transactionData.getType());
                    if(transactionData.getCategory().equals("Food")){
                        expenseInfo.setFood(expenseInfo.getFood()-transactionData.getAmount());
                    }
                    else if(transactionData.getCategory().equals("Rent")){
                        expenseInfo.setRent(expenseInfo.getRent()-transactionData.getAmount());
                    }
                    else if(transactionData.getCategory().equals("Transportation")){
                        expenseInfo.setTransportation(expenseInfo.getTransportation()-transactionData.getAmount());
                    }
                    else if(transactionData.getCategory().equals("Clothing")){
                        expenseInfo.setClothing(expenseInfo.getClothing()-transactionData.getAmount());
                    }
                    else if(transactionData.getCategory().equals("Communication")){
                        expenseInfo.setCommunication(expenseInfo.getCommunication()-transactionData.getAmount());
                    }
                    else if(transactionData.getCategory().equals("Books")){
                        expenseInfo.setBooks(expenseInfo.getBooks()-transactionData.getAmount());
                    }
                    else if(transactionData.getCategory().equals("Electronics")){
                        expenseInfo.setElectronics(expenseInfo.getElectronics()-transactionData.getAmount());
                    }
                    else if(transactionData.getCategory().equals("Project")){
                        expenseInfo.setProject(expenseInfo.getProject()-transactionData.getAmount());
                    }
                    else if(transactionData.getCategory().equals("Treat")){
                        expenseInfo.setTreat(expenseInfo.getTreat()-transactionData.getAmount());
                    }
                    else if(transactionData.getCategory().equals("Tuition")){
                        expenseInfo.setTuition(expenseInfo.getTuition()-transactionData.getAmount());
                    }
                    else if(transactionData.getCategory().equals("Education")){
                        expenseInfo.setEducation(expenseInfo.getEducation()-transactionData.getAmount());
                    }
                    else if(transactionData.getCategory().equals("Hangout")){
                        expenseInfo.setHangout(expenseInfo.getHangout()-transactionData.getAmount());
                    }
                    else if(transactionData.getCategory().equals("Trip")){
                        expenseInfo.setTrip(expenseInfo.getTrip()-transactionData.getAmount());
                    }
                    else if(transactionData.getCategory().equals("Utilities")){
                        expenseInfo.setUtilities(expenseInfo.getUtilities()-transactionData.getAmount());
                    }
                    else if(transactionData.getCategory().equals("Services")){
                        expenseInfo.setServices(expenseInfo.getServices()-transactionData.getAmount());
                    }
                    else if(transactionData.getCategory().equals("Fees")){
                        expenseInfo.setFees(expenseInfo.getFees()-transactionData.getAmount());
                    }
                    else if(transactionData.getCategory().equals("Tax")){
                        expenseInfo.setTax(expenseInfo.getTax()-transactionData.getAmount());
                    }
                    else {
                        if (expenseInfo != null) {
                            expenseInfo.setOthers(expenseInfo.getOthers()-transactionData.getAmount());
                        }
                    }
                    databaseReference.setValue(expenseInfo);
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final String transactionId = transactionData.getTransactionId();
        db.keepSynced(true);
        db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"on data change",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    TransactionData transactionData1 = dataSnapshot1.getValue(TransactionData.class);
                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(),transactionId + " " + transactionData1.getTransactionId().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if(transactionData1.getTransactionId().equals(transactionId)){
                        db.child(dataSnapshot1.getKey().toString()).removeValue();
                        transactionDataList.remove(position);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                       Toast.makeText(getContext(),"item deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Firebase json file is as

```js
{
  "F93sQbST7whWeT0ilYnahiO9wNo1": {
    "calender": {
      "2023": {
        "02": {
          "10": {
            "deposit": 200,
            "expense": 100
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "expenseInfo": {
      "2023": {
        "02": {
          "books": 0,
          "clothing": 0,
          "communication": 0,
          "education": 0,
          "electronics": 0,
          "fees": 0,
          "food": 100,
          "hangout": 0,
          "others": 0,
          "project": 0,
          "rent": 0,
          "services": 0,
          "tax": 0,
          "transportation": 0,
          "treat": 0,
          "trip": 0,
          "tuition": 0,
          "utilities": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "transactions": {
      "-NNw3hVUnakSVcZBKgEO": {
        "amount": 200,
        "category": "Tuition",
        "date": "10/02/2023",
        "transactionId": "-NNw3hVUnakSVcZBKgEO",
        "type": "Deposit"
      },
      "-NNw3nf6RGcPEiCIGY2X": {
        "amount": 100,
        "category": "Food",
        "date": "10/02/2023",
        "transactionId": "-NNw3nf6RGcPEiCIGY2X",
        "type": "Expense"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
public class ExpenseInfo {


private double food,rent,transportation,clothing,communication,books,electronics,project,treat,tuition,education,hangout,trip,utilities,services,fees,tax,others;
public ExpenseInfo() {
    food=0;
    rent =0;
    transportation=0;
    clothing=0;
    communication=0;
    books=0;
    electronics=0;
    project=0;
    treat=0;
    tuition=0;
    education=0;
    hangout=0;
    trip=0;
    utilities=0;
    fees=0;
    services=0;
    tax=0;
    others=0;
}

public double getFood() {
    return food;
}

public void setFood(double food) {
    this.food = food;
}

public double getRent() {
    return rent;
}

public void setRent(double rent) {
    this.rent = rent;
}

public double getTransportation() {
    return transportation;
}

public void setTransportation(double transportation) {
    this.transportation = transportation;
}

public double getClothing() {
    return clothing;
}

public void setClothing(double clothing) {
    this.clothing = clothing;
}

public double getCommunication() {
    return communication;
}

public void setCommunication(double communication) {
    this.communication = communication;
}

public double getBooks() {
    return books;
}

public void setBooks(double books) {
    this.books = books;
}

public double getElectronics() {
    return electronics;
}

public void setElectronics(double electronics) {
    this.electronics = electronics;
}

public double getProject() {
    return project;
}

public void setProject(double project) {
    this.project = project;
}

public double getTreat() {
    return treat;
}

public void setTreat(double treat) {
    this.treat = treat;
}

public double getTuition() {
    return tuition;
}

public void setTuition(double tuition) {
    this.tuition = tuition;
}

public double getEducation() {
    return education;
}

public void setEducation(double education) {
    this.education = education;
}

public double getHangout() {
    return hangout;
}

public void setHangout(double hangout) {
    this.hangout = hangout;
}

public double getTrip() {
    return trip;
}

public void setTrip(double trip) {
    this.trip = trip;
}

public double getUtilities() {
    return utilities;
}

public void setUtilities(double utilities) {
    this.utilities = utilities;
}

public double getServices() {
    return services;
}

public void setServices(double services) {
    this.services = services;
}
public double getFees() {
    return fees;
}
public void setFees(double fees) {
    this.fees = fees;
}
public double getTax() {
    return tax;
}
public void setTax(double tax) {
    this.tax = tax;
}
public double getOthers() {
    return others;
}
public void setOthers(double others) {
    this.others = others;
}
```

Here
ExpenseInfo expenseInfo = dataSnapshot.getValue(ExpenseInfo.class);

this expenseInfo returns null value. How can it be non null?
I've tried to fix this but was unable to do so.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I have added the json file, please check it now

Comment: Are you sure all children do contain a field `tuition`?

Answer (score 0):

You can just check for null value like below.

```
else if(transactionData.getCategory().equals("Tuition")){
   if (expenseInfo.getTuition() != null)
      expenseInfo.setTuition(expenseInfo.getTuition()-transactionData.getAmount());
   }
}
```

For NullPointerExceptions you can check if that particular value is non-null.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work sir